# Custom query at top of archive search page, arguments are overridden

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I am using a customised archive template for a custom post type.

At the top of the page, I'd like to show a specific post, found using a new `wp_query()` call.

```
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'document',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_date( 'F Y' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Custom search form

```
<form id="document-filter" method="post">
    <select name="order_by">
        <option value="date">Date</option>
        <option value="title">Name</option>
    </select>
    <select name="order">
        <option value="desc">DESC</option>
        <option value="asc">ASC</option>
    </select>
    <input name="s" type="text" placeholder="Filter by keyword" value=""/>
    <input name="post_type" type="hidden" value="document"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Initially, it works. However, if I then use the custom search form to either sort the archive list (date/name, asc/desc), the custom `wp_query()` is affected, and the `query_vars` array is overriding my supplied arguments.

Example

Posts, in date order, descending:

1. Post C
2. Post B
3. Post A

Initially, my custom query at the top of the page will output `Post C`, which is correct.

If I use the search/filter form to change the order of the posts to:

1. Post A
2. Post B
3. Post C

The singular queried post will now be `Post A`, which is incorrect. My custom query args have not changed, but are being overridden by the search form somehow.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem here. Can you add more information about the issue?

Comment: note that `the_title` and `the_date` output internally, those echo statements are unnecessary

Comment: Also, how does the custom search form work? Looking at your query I don't see how anything on the template page could interfere with it, we'll need to see the custom search code

Comment: @TomJNowell yea, I actually had some HTML mixed in but removed it for clarity. I've added the custom search form code in now.

Comment: From the code so far I don't see why would global context possibly interfere with this standalone query. I would guess a case of something hooking into queries and not making proper checks to target just the right ones.

Comment: @Rarst any clue on how to do so in this case?

Comment: Try with plugins off, core theme, and such.

Comment: @Rarst yea, that doesn't help. This _should_ work in theory, just need to understand why the query vars are interfering with a new wp_query..

Answer (score 0):

In my experience wp_reset_postdata() does not work well. You can try this code:

```
global $wp_query;
$temp_wp_query = $wp_query;
//Your custom WP_Query code
$wp_query = $temp_wp_query;
```

Comment: Tried this solution, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got this working, but not using `wp_query()`.

Instead, I had to use a custom query with `$wpdb`.

Example:

```
$latest_document = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = %s
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = %s
        ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
        LIMIT 1
     ", 'publish', 'document' ), OBJECT );
```

What is interesting is that whilst I am only wanting a single row, when I used `$wpdb->get_row()` I got the same issue as before, where the resulting record would be sorted by the parameters from the search form.

Using `$wpdb->get_results()` works fine and the record is consistently the same, regardless of the sorting I select using the search form.